# Adding a glossary entry for an unreferenced term

Tags: glossaries

I am using the glossary package.

I want to include terms in the glossary that are not referred to in the text.

That sounds weird, but it's not --- the terms are actually included in a figure, and I don't intend to write about them in the body of the text, but rather refer my reader to the glossary.

How can I force the inclusion of a term in the glossary without using the `\gls` command or otherwise referencing the term in the text. I took a look at the manual but it was not clear to me how to accomplish this even in light of that info.

thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0):

I used glsaddall to solve this. I hadn't used it yet and terms were showing up in the glossary probably on account of my referencing them.